# The number of maps $f$ from the set $\{1,2,3\}$ into the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $f(i)\le f(j)$, whenever $i<j$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

The number of maps $f$ from the set $\{1,2,3\}$ into the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $f(i)\le f(j)$, whenever $i<j$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to choose the $3$ function values $f(1),f(2),f(3)$ from $5$ possibilities, with repetition allowed.  The order of the $3$ chosen numbers is not important, because once you have chosen them, the condition $f(i)\le f(j)$ tells you which is $f(1)$, which is $f(2)$ and which is $f(3)$.

The number of choices of $3$ elements from $5$, with order not important and repetition allowed, is
$$C(5+3-1,3)=C(7,3)=35\ .$$
For the ideas behind this see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: Isn't the formula $\binom {n+k-1}{k-1}$ ? In your case you have $3$ boxes namely, $f(1),f(2),f(3)$ , so shouldn't it be $\binom {5+3-1}{3-1} = \binom {7}{2}$ ?

Comment: @StrangerForever No, we have 5 boxes, namely the 5 possible values 1,2,3,4,5, and therefore 4 "gaps" or "dividers" between them.  We have 3 items, namely the three chosen numbers (possibly including repetitions).  So we arrange 3 items and 4 dividers in a row by choosing the 3 places for the items: $C(7,3)$ ways... (continued)

Comment: Alternatively we could choose the places for the dividers, giving $C(7,4)$ which is the same.  This is probably the formula you were thinking of, but you have applied it incorrectly.  In any case since the numbers are very small, it is pretty easy to list all possibilities and confirm that $35$ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint - Suppose you map $1$ to $1$, now if $2$ maps to $1$ then $3$ can map to $1,2,3,4$ or $5$, Similarly if $2$ maps to $2$ then $3$ will have $4$ choices to map to, so the total no of functions when $1$ maps to $1$ is

$(5+4+3+2+1)$

Similarly count the others when $1$ maps to $2,3,4$ or $5$

Comment: Maybe a bit easier: The number of functions where $2$ maps to $1$ is $1\times5$ because then $1$ maps to $1$ and $3$ maps to $1,2,3,4$ or $5$; likewise the number of functions where $2$ maps to $2$ is $2\times4$ etc., so the answer is $1\times5+2\times4+3\times3+4\times2+5\times1=35.$

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered another way to solve this question:-
There are basically three cases possible:-

1. All the three mappings i.e. f(1),f(2) and f(3) are distinct.
   So, we will just choose any three and they will arrange themselves automatically so as to satisfy the condition f(i)<f(j).
   Therefore the number of ways is C(5,3) = 10.
2. Two of the mappings are similar.
   In this case, we will choose any two numbers - C(5,2)*2 = 20.
   A factor of "2" has to be multiplied because after we have chosen two numbers ,there can be two cases of repetition. For example if we choose 2 and 3, the two cases are "2,2,3" and "2,3,3".
3. All mappings are same.
   Number of ways = 5 since there are 5 elements in the second set and we can choose any one of them.

So, finally the answer is 10+20+5 = 35.